# How to do it correctly: grep -ri '->'

Tags: linux, shell

```
cat a.txt | grep -ri '->'
```

I want to grep lines with text arrow ->. 
But in linux shell
 `-` means starts of an option
and 
  `>` means pipe output to a file.

So after doing command given above ,I got error

```
[root@rs169 document_root]# cat a.txt | grep -ri '->'
grep: invalid option -- '>'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Can someone tell how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 11):

Another way of doing it is to use `--` - this tells grep that you have finished using flags, and any `-` appearing after this is to be interpreted literally.

```
$ echo "->" | grep -- "->"
->
```

Comment: Using `--` is the way go. `-` is not a character that needs escaping.

Answer (score 4):

`grep -ri '\->'  a.txt`  should do

```
[A]$ grep -ri '\->'  a.txt
12 ->2
[A]$ cat a.txt
12 ->2
11

[A]$ sh -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: OK, then it may depend on the shell used. For me it do not work (bash 4.2.45).

Comment: Ahhh, the problem is stackoverflow's markdown! Satya did include `\-`, but stackoverflow doesn't show it. @Satya you should edit your first line to put it in backticks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `-e` key to explicitly state the pattern: `grep -rie '->'`

```
 -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add that `e` should be the last option, i.e. `grep -rie '->' ...` would work, but `grep -ier '->' ...` wouldn't.

Comment: I'd even put it as a separate option myself: `grep -ri -e '->'`

Comment: `e` doesn't have to be _last_ option. It just have to go together with pattern. Which is what is said in man. I don't think this requires any clarification.

Answer (score 2):

On linux command shell, you escape the `-`
Like this

```
cat a.txt | grep -ri '\->'
```

BTW why do you need `-ri` option ? `->` doesn't have any alphabet (`-i` is for case insensitive search) and cat a.txt won't produce a list of recursive files/pipes that you need to search

Answer (score 2):

While you may escape `-` in the pattern, the reason that it doesn't work is: `grep` is led to think that `>` (part of the pattern `->`) is an option passed to it.  Since `grep` doesn't have an option `>`, it complains.

The *correct* way would be to tell grep to stop expecting options by adding `--`:

```
cat a.txt | grep -ri -- '->'
```

Comment: Side note: `< a.txt grep -ri -- '->'` avoids an unnecessary `fork()`/`exec()`

Comment: @Shahbaz For that matter, even the other options `-r` and `-i` for grep are useless in *this* particular case.  People are used to specifying those without understanding what those imply.